# Increase QTabWidget tab size while using custom palette

Tags: css, qt

My app uses a `QTabWidget`. I want the tabs to fill the entire length of the tab bar. 
My app also uses a palette to set the colors of all widgets, forms, etc.

I found that I can set the tab size as intended like so:

```
ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet(QString("QTabBar::tab { width: %1px; }").arg(ui->tabWidget->size().width()/ui->tabWidget->count()));
```

But this causes the tab widget and all of its children to ignore my palette.

How can I use my palette and also increase the tab size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your described behavior, but I was not able to do so. I'm using Qt 5.13.0, maybe it is in older version. At first I also thought, that I reproduced your behavior, but then I recognized, that I just didn't fully understood the options in `QPalette`, which really has a lot of ColorGroups and ColorRoles with different meanings.

Try the following simple test runner in order to verify it with your Qt Version.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto p=app.palette();
    p.setColor(QPalette::ColorGroup::Active, QPalette::ColorRole::Background, QColor("red"));
    p.setColor(QPalette::ColorGroup::Active, QPalette::ColorRole::Foreground, QColor("blue"));
    p.setColor(QPalette::ColorGroup::Active, QPalette::ColorRole::ButtonText, QColor("magenta"));  
    app.setPalette(p);
    auto w= new QTabWidget;
    auto f=new QFrame;
    f->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
    f->layout()->addWidget(new QPushButton("Test"));
    w->addTab(f,"Tab1");
    w->setStyleSheet(QString("QTabBar::tab { width: %1px; height: %1px }").arg(100));
    w->show(); 
    app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Your example worked, so I did some experimenting. Turns out setting a stylesheet makes widgets ignore palettes that are set in the designer as "inherited", but to get around this you can make your palette for your form in the designer and then in main call `app.setPalette(myForm.palette())` which has the desired effect. Thanks!